# How to get column with list of values from another column in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can someone help me with any idea how to create pyspark DataFrame with all Recepients of each person?

For example:

**Input DataFrame:**

```
+------+---------+
|Sender|Recepient|
+------+---------+
|Alice | Bob     |
|Alice | John    |
|Alice | Mike    |
|Bob   | Tom     |
|Bob   | George  |
|George| Alice   |
|George| Bob     |
+------+---------+
```

**Result:**

```
+------+------------------+
|Sender|Recepients        |
+------+------------------+
|Alice |[Bob, John, Mike] |
|Bob   |[Tom, George]     |
|George|[Alice, Bob]      |
+------+------------------+
```

I tried `df.groupBy("Sender").sum("Recepients")` to get string and split it but had the error `Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need was to do was a `groupBy Sender` column and `collect the Recepient`.

Below is the full solution

```
# create a data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
("Alice","Bob"),
("Alice","John"),
("Alice","Mike"),
("Bob","Tom"),
("Bob","George"),
("George","Alice"),
("George","Bob")], 
("sender","Recepient"))

df.show()

# results below
+------+---------+
|Sender|Recepient|
+------+---------+
|Alice | Bob     |
|Alice | John    |
|Alice | Mike    |
|Bob   | Tom     |
|Bob   | George  |
|George| Alice   |
|George| Bob     |
+------+---------+

# Import functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# perform a groupBy and use collect_list
df1 = df.groupby("Sender").agg(f.collect_list('Recepient').alias('Recepients'))
df1.show()
# results
+------+------------------+
|Sender|Recepients        |
+------+------------------+
|Alice |[Bob, John, Mike] |
|Bob   |[Tom, George]     |
|George|[Alice, Bob]      |
+------+------------------+
```